# TypeError at / TodoListServices.list_todo_paginate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'page'

Tags: python, django

//Views

```
class TodoList(APIView):
    def get(self,request,page=None, format=None):

        todos = []
        if page is not None:
           todos = TodoListServices.list_todo_paginate(page)

        else:
            todos = TodoListServices.list_todo_paginate(1)

        serializer = TodoSerializer(todos, many=True, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

//Services

```
class TodoListServices:
    @staticmethod
    def list_todo_paginate(page):
        page_number = page
        page_size = 10
        if page_number is None:
            page_number = 1

        todos = todo.objects.all()[
                (page_number - 1) * page_size: page_number * page_size
                ]

        return todos
```

I am getting a TypeError : missing 1 required positional argument
how do I solve this ?

Comment: What is the **full** traceback? We know there is a missing positional argument, but that doesn't tell us where it is.

Comment: it was in 

class TodoListServices:
    @staticmethod
    def list_todo_paginate(page): // this line

Answer (score 0):

I solved it . Turns out  I need to

set page = 1 as default

```
@staticmethod
    def list_todo_paginate(page=1):
        page_number = page
        page_size = 10
```

The reason the  version of list_todo_paginate with the default parameter (page=1) does not cause an issue is that it provides a default value for the page parameter. When you call this method without explicitly passing the page argument, it automatically assumes the value of 1, which is the default.

In contrast, the second version of list_todo_paginate without a default parameter requires you to explicitly pass a value for the page parameter. If you do not provide this value when calling the method, Python will raise a "missing 1 required positional argument" error because it expects you to provide a value for page.